# How to remove a css class?

Tags: css, display

I am showing a c3 chart (vue-c3) inside a div. 
I have attached the images showing the `display:block` getting over-ridden by *c3* class. The first row in the table shows the desired behaviour (that is the row for which I removed the *c3* class using the Chrome `Elements` tab).
How do I remove the *c3* class ? Or how do I force `display:block` (`!important` and using `inline-style` did not work)?

[after removing c3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXs42.png)

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrCUn.png)

Update:
I don't even have to add `display:block` anywhere. Merely removing c3 gives the desired result. The code is

```
<template>
  <div >
    <vue-c3  :handler="handler"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You have to write "display:block" in style="" not class=""

Comment: no, that didn't work either

Comment: have you tried `<div class="vuec3-chart c3" style="display:block !important">`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out someone else had written this code in `override.styl` global css file:

```
.vuec3-chart.c3 > svg{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

commented it out, and everything worked as desired without writing any style or class.
What made it difficult to track was the fact that there existed a file `c3.styl` where I was looking for global css but this code was in `override.styl`.

Comment: Did you use th browser console to inspect the element? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/  That can speed things up in finding out where css styles are coming from and what overrides what.